# angular2 - Is it possible to get the parent property thats being binded to a child components input?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Ok, so this involves some digging under Angular 2's hood. But consider these two components:

*parent.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `<child [item]="test"></child>`
 })
class ParentComponent () { 
  test = 'hello world'; 
  test2 = 'hello space';
}
```

*child.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<p>{{item}}</p>`
 })
class ChildComponent () { @Input() item }
```

Is it possible to determine which attribute in the parent is being used to bind to the child component's `item` property? I can get a components list of inputs using Reflect metadata, and using `DebugElement` I can get a reference to the ParentComponent through the `_parent` property, which gives me access to the attributes of the ParentComponent class, but this doesn't help much.

Is there any way, possibly through Reflect metadata to get the attribute name that the parent component is using to bind to some child component's input? Note, that I don't want to modify these sample components at all, I want to determine this information using Angulars internal information.